# Removing soap envelope from WSO2 proxy

Tags: xml, soap, wso2, sequence, wso2-esb

Every outbound message from the WSO2 proxy service is wrapped by a soap envelope by default.

Any possibility to remove it by configuration?
I want the transformed message from the proxy service without SOAP envelope.

I dont want to write another class to handle this.

```
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="risresult" transports="https,http,jms" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="ContentType" value="text/plain" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <class name="com.test.guru.HL7RISPrescription"/>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
         <header name="To" action="remove"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="jms:/prescription?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616" format="pox" />
                </endpoint>
            </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <drop/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
      <rules>                           
         <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>                           
         <default>application/xml</default>                  
      </rules>
   </parameter>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

Regards
Guru
@gnanagurus

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  format="pox"
```

to send the XML to endpoint Please refer following blog post for more details.

http://charithaka.blogspot.com/2010/07/message-format-transformations-with.html

Comment: Hello Shelan, Adding format option doesn't work. This is my address configuration: <address uri="jms:/reports?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616" format="pox"/>

Comment: This should work. Is it possible to share the proxy's configuration. This is an exact example for your use case. http://nuwanwimalasekara.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-send-messages-to-jms-endpoint.html

Comment: Shelan, I have updated my question with my proxy service configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following property just above the send mediator to remove the soap envelope from the message.

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```

I tested it with following sample proxy and it worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
           name="test"
           transports="https,http"
           statistics="disable"
           trace="disable"
           startOnLoad="true">
       <target>
          <inSequence>

             <property name="messageType"
                       value="application/xml"
                       scope="axis2"
                       type="STRING"/>
             <log level="full"/>
             <send>
                <endpoint>
                   <address uri="http://www.google.com"/>
                </endpoint>
             </send>
          </inSequence>
       </target>
       <description/>
    </proxy>
```